# View 3D image in different directions in iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

How can I develop an iphone application that will allow the user to see the image in different directions (like view the image in side view, top view, front view, etc.)?

Initially the image is in front view. If the user selects side-view, I have to do a camera effect to go to side-view.

What technology do I have to use? Is it openGL? Any Ideas?

Comment: You mention using a camera effect. Are you showing a camera image in different views or will you be showing a 3D object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d, a 2-d game engine for iphone, has a 3-d extension. It's free.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/